# catch user activity

Tags: xorg, wayland

I'm working on app reminder for saving eyes. And the question is the following - 
Is there any way to monitor user activity programmatically- if user type something or using mouse?
I need no exact keys codes are being pressed or cursor location. My only need is the fact that user is doing something. 
No root privileges and app does not have any window.

Comment: What do you want to do with that. Are you writing some script or app?

Comment: yep, if i detect user have no activity - i stop reminder timer that user spend too much time at the computer.